# Migration Visual Web Part from Sharepoint 2010 to Sharepoint 2013 - Web.Config error

Tags: migration, visual-web-part

I am migrating a webpart with `2 External List` and `9 normal list` from `Sharepoint 2010` to `Sharepoint 2013`.

After migrating i Geting this error. May be I hard coded something in Web.config file. Please help me:

[image]

Comment: In the tekst it look this way: Could not load the Web.config configuration file. Check the file for any malformed XML elements, and try agaim. The following error occurred: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: are you trying to access something from web.config ? if yes please check the key

Comment: No i dont want to Access something. I want only migrate my solution.

Answer (score 0):

I can menage after ad to Alternate Mapping Default adress for my Developer Server. And it works.

Comment: Could you explain a litte mor detailed which steps to take? Thank you!